# How to delay loading of iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, delay

I was just wondering, how I could delay iframe load by 5 seconds? I only know html and css so far, and don't have time, atleast this year to start javascript.

Anyway, for a website I'm working on, I need iframe to load after 5 seconds. Any help would be well appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay load of iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587523/delay-load-of-iframe)

Answer (score 3):

you will need to use Javascript, say in your html file:

```
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

<script>
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://...');
    }, 5000);    
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it wont load? Here is jsfiddle example I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/6ysa72cb/

Comment: www.google.com block loading within a iframe if it's not under the same origin, change your url to https://jsfiddle.net