# How to make youtube <ifram> delay loading

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I am using youtube html  tag to loading the youtube video in webside,but it takes a lot of time to loading webpage,so can any one knows how to make delay on html tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay load of iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587523/delay-load-of-iframe)

Comment: Have you tried linking to a short video? Are all attempts to load a video taking a long time to load?  Once it loads, if a second attempt is made, does the second attempt take about the same time to load?